# How to fetch all users report from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to fetch all visiting users row by row via Google Analytics API?

Information I would like to get is like
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting but `User Activity API` allows me to fetch tagged users with User ID, while I need all users, sessions etc from given time range (something like - fetch me all users/sessions visited yesterday in rowset manner) without having to pass `User ID`.

Comment: I think the only way you can do that is if you have crated a custom dimension with user id that you are sending to all your requests.

Comment: @DaImTo If I understood correctly, you suggest to tag *all* of my visitors same `User ID` and then ask API with this `User ID`, right?

Comment: userid should be set to the user ID of the user then you will be able to use the API to request session data for that user its going to have to be unique for each user

Comment: The report you want is analytics of your site access.  Note "YOUR SITE".  You know the user ids of your users.